# Values saved in Redis using Spring Data have weird prefixes

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm using Spring Data Redis with Kotlin but without Spring data repositories because of the shortcoming in [DATAREDIS-1250](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-1250).
So, I created my own little repository.

```
interface CoroutinesRepository<T : Serializable> {
    suspend fun save(entity: T): T
    suspend fun findByIdOrNull(id: String): T?
    suspend fun deleteById(id: String)
}
```

and its implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractCoroutinesRepository<T : Serializable>(clazz: Class<T>) : CoroutinesRepository<T> {
    private val hash: String = clazz.simpleName
        .// convert class name to hyphenated string
    private val idField: Field = clazz.declaredFields
        .// find field with @Id annotation

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<Any, Any>
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var persistenceProperties: PersistenceProperties

    override suspend fun save(entity: T): T {
        val valueOps = redisTemplate
            .opsForValue()
        valueOps.set("$hash:${idField.get(entity)}", entity, getTtl(persistenceProperties))
            .awaitFirst()
        return entity
    }
    // Other methods omitted
}
```

used as:

```
@Repository
class ResponseRepositoryImpl : AbstractCoroutinesRepository<Response>(Response::class.java)
```

This works and the above code can set and get values from Redis. However, when I query from Redis CLI, I see:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0
1) "0"
2) 1) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0cuuid:test"
   2) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x10response:test"
```

What is this weird string prefix? As I said, it doesn't seem to affect the retrieval, but I'm curious.

Spring Data Redis 2.3.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be due the use of default `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`, and I'm guessing the weirdness is the field meta information (type etc). Other Redis serializers like `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` don't do this, and the data is saved in a human-readable format.